# Create a trigger checking dates between two tables and updating an attribute if true

Tags: sql

How could you make a SQL trigger checking if two datetime attributes are equal between two tables? and if so updating an attribute in one of the tables to 1?

I am new to SQL triggers, so guidance could be helpful

Comment: Hi Chris. Triggers are controlled by actions over the tables data. Either insert, update or delete. What kind of trigger are you trying to do? The implementation can be different depending on the type of trigger

Comment: Hi Eduardo. I am not really sure.. The check should happen when the datetime on table 2 is bigger than table 1. Therefore, I would like the trigger to happen afterwards an insert, if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Could it be something like this? I'm assuming you want to set value1 to `1` on Table2 after an insert on Table1

```
CREATE TRIGGER TRG_SetValueOne
ON dbo.Table1
AFTER INSERT AS
BEGIN
UPDATE T2 
Set Value1 = 1
FROM INSERTED I
INNER JOIN db.Table2 as T2 on I.Attribute1 = T2.Atribute1
WHERE T2.DateAttribute1 > I.DateAttribute
END
GO
```